# A composite class with an associative relationship to a separate class

Tags: ruby, uml

Using modules and classes, what is the best way to define this class relationship?

[image: UML class diagram for aggregation and association]

A commodity has zero or more price series' (aggregation), And a price series object is created by selecting part of an ExcelFile object.

(An excel file object is an excel workbook that has been converted to a json-like structure)

I'm thinking that the ExcelFile class should be a separate class class... Then I can instantiate a Commodity (e.g. `gold = Commodity.new("gold")`). I can instantiate an Excel file (e.g. `yahoo_prices = ExcelFile.new(xlsx_file_name)`).

But now I want to instantiate a PriceSeries object (within the commodity object) using the ExcelFile object outside of the Commodity namespace.

How can I do this? Should I do this? Am I on the right track?

This is what I think it should be:

```
class ExcelFile
end

class Commodity 
    class PriceSeries
    end
end
```

This "program" will be one feature in a much larger program. Would it be a good idea to put all these classes in a module and then mix it into the "main" class eventually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.  However, your diagram is showing an aggregation rather than an internal class, as your code has it.  So they aren't quite consistent with one another.  I think you should go with your diagram and change your code:

```
class ExcelFile
end

class Commodity
    PriceSeries[] myPriceSeriesArray
end

class PriceSeries
end
```

There's more to it than this, of course: you have to have a way to create PriceSeries instances and assign them to the myPriceSeriesArray array among other things.  But that's the basic idea.

Now, there are a few things about your diagram:

1. `*` is short for `0..*`.  Since you need at least one PriceSeries and one ExcelFile, you need to change these to `1..*`.  (This assumes that you can have any number of either, so long as you have at least one.)
2. I would suggest that you put the `<<file>>` stereotype on your ExcelFile class.
3. Consider making your association between Commodity and PriceSeries a composition rather than an aggregation (black diamond instead of white).  This means that your PriceSeries class's lifetime is tied to the lifetime of the Commodity class.  It doesn't look like a PriceSeries instance has any logical identity that's independent of the Commodity, so when you dispose of a Commodity object I would think that you would also dispose of the PriceSeries object.  If you decide to do this, your code should instantiate necessary PriceSeries objects in Commodity's constructor and assign them to the myPriceSeriesArray attribute.

Comment: Thank you, that is an incredibly helpful answer. I have another question if its' ok :). Price series' differ by who maintains them and what they reflect (i.e. a futures vs a spot price). They also have different frequencies. What I was going to do was keep each price series as a hash assigned to a variable , e.g. gold_spot = {:date => "price", etc}. Is there a reason to use an array over this method?

Comment: Ok, so let's say wheat has a spot price and a futures price.  Those are two different series.  What you're beginning to talk about here is the different attributes of a price series.  What are they?  I'm seeing maybe a seriesType, a maintainedBy and a frequency from what you're saying here.  But I'm not really sure what a "price series" is exactly.  Is it a series of discrete values?  If so, what affects which value is the actual price?  As for using an array (collection, whatever), it's the best way to associate a variable number of objects of the same type with another object.

Comment: A price series can either be a series of unique values, or an index of relative changes worked out as function of other things. For example, the dollar doesn't have an absolute value but a value relative to an average of other currencies or commodities. This program is going to take a price series and compare to different dates' prices. At this point I'm not going to keep track of the attributes of the price series. But because I want each price ties to a date I would have to use a hash I think

Comment: Well, no, you could also have (and probably should have) a Price object, which is a composite of PriceSeries.  You can keep anything you want to with it.  Also, (and obviously) you should keep track of attributes that are necessary to model the problem, and you should not keep track of those that are not.  The array of PriceSeries objects has to do with having more than one PriceSeries associated with a Commodity.  Each one of those could contain an array of Price objects.

Comment: Also, I don't know what language you're working with, but I wouldn't typically consider a hash table as a first choice for storing a bunch of key-value pairs.  There are all kinds of ways to read JSON data from a file.

Comment: ok, so it would be worth creating the json and writing it to a file? I'm working in Ruby

Comment: Sorry Zach, but we're beginning to get too far off-topic.  Perhaps it would be better to address your implementation concerns in a new thread.  Before I could try to answer that I'd need to know more about what you're trying to do.